# Can I get the compiler version from compiler properties in meson?

Tags: build, build-system, meson-build

In meson build system, can I get the compiler version in addition to the compiler name from the compiler properties?

For example, you can get the C++ compiler name like so:

```
compiler = meson.get_compiler('cpp')
compilerName = compiler.get_id()
```

This returns strings like 'clang', 'gcc', 'msvc', etc. I'm wondering if there's a way to get the version information as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it turns out this is possible even though it wasn't documented on the wiki.

```
compiler = meson.get_compiler('cpp')
compiler_version = compiler.version()
```